# Get openstack public url of an object

Tags: openstack

I am using openstack to upload an object to a container like explained here:
https://docs.openstack.org/openstacksdk/latest//user/guides/object_store.html#uploading-objects

I would like to know if it is possible to programmatically know the public url of the file that I just uploaded.

I am using the python openstack sdk framework but I cannot find a method to have this with any of the endpoints that are available there.

Answer (score 1):

The Object Storage API supports the standard, non-serialized response format, which is the default, and both JSON and XML serialized response formats.I you are authorized , you can  get it like :

```
/v1/{account}/{container}/{object}
```

```
/v1/12345678912345/my_files/mypicture01.jpg
```

For example, if the endpoint for Object Storage is objects.mycloud.com, the returned URL is "https://objects.openstackmycloud.com/v1/12345678912345/my_files".

To access a container, append the container name to the resource path.

To access an object, append the container and the object name to the path.

Comment: Do you know if the python frameworks makes it available somehow ?

Answer (score 1):

I guess  openstack using  swift  for  object store,  in that case you can use the swift python client:

https://docs.openstack.org/python-swiftclient/latest/service-api.html

Comment: Which endpoint is providing the public url ? I cannot find it

Answer (score 0):

The endpoint is defined in your  openstack  and you can list  the endpoints  with

```
openstack endpoint list
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't directly related to programmatic access in Python, but for future google searchers, here are two methods I've found:

### Via GUI

Go to Object Store -> Containers in the OpenStack dashboard, then click on your container. If you check "Public Access", then the following link will appear:
[image]

### Via CLI

You have to have `python-swiftclient` installed and the appropriate credentials configured:

1. Run `swift stat <container>`. If the output includes  `Read ACL: .r:*` then it has public access, so you're all good. If not, use `swift post --read-acl .r:* <container>`
2. Get the swift base URL using `swift auth`. It will output something like `OS_STORAGE_URL=https://object-store.some.host/v1/AUTH_06d6e708e3e642da99d846ba3ea629c5`. This URL is the base URL you will use to calculate the public URL.
3. The final public URL will be `{base}/{container}/{object}`, e.g. for an object called `object.txt` in container `container`, the URL would be `https://object-store.some.host/v1/AUTH_06d6e708e3e642da99d846ba3ea629c5/container/object.txt`

Comment: So this is the only way to use this "link", if I understand correctly? Is the link, specifically this part, `AUTH_06d6e708e3e642da99d846ba3ea629c5` public?